# Delphi became unregistered when I upgraded to Windows 7

Tags: windows, delphi

I've been using DELPHI 6 with Vista very successfully, however, after upgrading to Windows 7 my Delphi 6 is no longer registered. Even after successfully registering it on-line, it will not save it, and as such, never gets registered.  How can I register it?

Comment: I think this question should probably go to embarcadero http://www.embarcadero.com/

Comment: Are you running Delphi as an administrator (not an admin account, but actually running the program as admin)? I'm fairly certain you have to do that in order for the registration to stick in D6.

Comment: Yes I am.  However, why, upon upgrading from Vista to Windows 7, did my registered installation of Delphi 6 become unregistered, and when I attempt to register it, it completes it with no errors, but it never becomes registered?

Comment: Use Admin rights and set WinXP SP3 or Win Vista compatability mode.

Comment: Delphi up to version 7 did not enforce registration but only displays a small notice in the splash screen. So why is a failing registration a problem?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but can you see in the output of the compiler (e.g., in EXE and DLL files) that the product was not registered?

Comment: On newer Delphi Versions some virus scanners make Delphi appear unregistered, try disabling yours and check again

Answer (score 9):

The same problem on Win 10 is solved:

1. In register `HKEYCU->SOFTWARE->BORLAND->6.0` delete row `LM` (REG_BINARY)
2. Save
3. Run register form of Delphi with Embarcadero account

Now Delphi 6 should be registered and work ok.

Comment: Thanks for this. I  can confirm that removing that reg value enabled my previously failing registration attempts to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possible solutions:

- Use the [Windows XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) feature of Windows 7 to run Delphi 6.
- Run Delphi 6 as Administrator using elevated privileges (for instance by using [this trick](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html)).
- Run Delphi 6 in a VM (actually: Windows XP mode is a VM too)

--jeroen

Comment: @gbrandt: No, don't turn off UAC. It's foolish to downgrade security on the entire system because you don't want to do the work to make things function properly.

Comment: @Ken: it fixes the problem as asked, Delphi 6 will probably run fine.

Comment: @gbrandt: going back to Windows 2000 fixes the problem too, but somehow both of those harsh resolutions do not sound like something the OP really wants.

Comment: @Ken: really?  His question clear states he wants to move to Windows 7, so of course he would not want to move to Windows 2000.  Turning off UAC would solve the problem, as would other steps.  You don't have to like the solution, but it is still one of many solutions.

Comment: @gbrandt: I didn't say anything about Win2K. However, I still disagree that turning off UAC is a solution. First, it opens up huge security holes unnecessarily, and second, it postpones your learning to properly deal with the issues that UAC exposes. The second is really important - who says how long you'll be able to turn off UAC in the future, and what do you do when you can't and you don't have a clue what to do? Lazy hackish workarounds to avoid dealing with the problem are not the solution. Educating yourself works much better, IMO.

Comment: @Ken:  Sorry, that was Jeroen that talked about Win2K, my mistake.

Comment: These aren't really solutions. Delphi 6 can run on Win10.